# Convert multiple select query to Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

### Tables:

`items` with field `id`

```
id 
--
1
2
3
```

`item_photos` with fields `id, item_id, photo,status`. Status is 0 or 1.

```
id | item_id | photo | status
-----------------------------
1        1      a.jpg    1
2        1      b.jpg    1
3        1      c.jpg    2
4        2      d.jpg    1
```

item_photos item_id is a foreign key on items.id

### Entities:

Item entity has OneToMany on ItemPhoto

```
class Item { 
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemPhoto", mappedBy="item")
 */
private $itemPhotos;
```

### Problem:

I want to return all records from `items`, together with either one photo with status=2 or any other first photo for the same item_id in the item_photos table, or null if no photos found, **in a single query**.

Note: not all items have photos in `item_photos` with status=2.

In a Repository class I have this so far, it works but not what I want:

```
//Solution can be using query builder, or create query, doesn't matter
//
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$dql = "SELECT i,
      (SELECT p.photo FROM AppBundle:ItemPhoto p WHERE p.status='2' AND p.item=i.id) as photo1,
    FROM AppBundle:Item i";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
```

When I add another select into this query `(SELECT p.photo FROM AppBundle:ItemPhoto p WHERE p.item=i.id LIMIT 0,1) as photo2`, it gives me error. I could write it with SQL using IFNULL() but then DQL doesn't support IFNULL out of the box.

Comment: what error gives you sql (after adding second select)?

Comment: it says, p already defined `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 172 near 'p WHERE p.item=i.id': Error: 'p' is already defined.`. If I rename p with c, it complaints about `LIMIT`. If I remove LIMIT (more than 1 rows are returned obviously), it complains `Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row`